# Javascript - how can I properly shrink this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Regarding the browser version, the player height should change

```
if older then ie9 
  //height is fixed
else 
  //height is auto
```

The above code is working but, it's the worst thing I've seen, because I do repeat myself again and again, when only one line changes on this conditional.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<9) {
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () 
            {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", 
                {
                    m4v: "/video/videoK.mp4",
                    ogv: "/video/videoK.ogg"
                }).jPlayer("play");

                $('article.about-k').hide();
                olark('api.box.hide');
            },
            swfPath: "/scripts/",
            supplied: "m4v, ogv",
            size: {
                width: "100%",
                height: "400px" // THE ONLY CHANGE IS HERE
            },
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            click: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("play");
            },
            ended: function() {
                $('.jplayer-k').hide();
                $('article.about-k').show();
            }
        })
      } else {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () 
            {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", 
                {
                    m4v: "/video/videoK.mp4",
                    ogv: "/video/videoK.ogg"
                }).jPlayer("play");

                $('article.about-k').hide();
                olark('api.box.hide');
            },
            swfPath: "/scripts/",
            supplied: "m4v, ogv",
            size: {
                width: "100%",
                height: "auto" // THE ONLY CHANGE IS HERE
            },
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            click: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("play");
            },
            ended: function() {
                $('.jplayer-k').hide();
                $('article.about-k').show();
            }
        })
      }

    });
</script>
```

As noted by the comments, the only change is on ONE single line.
How can I remake this, without stupidly repeating myself ?

```
 height: "auto" //THIS IS THE ONLY DIFFERENCE!
```

Please advice

Comment: Little off-topic but, `$.browser.version.substr(0,1)` will most likely return `1` for IE 10 which may be unwanted. Use `parseInt($.browser.version, 10)` instead.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I'm not getting how can I use that: `parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9` ? Browser version ten less then 9... not getting... :)

Comment: `if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10)<9) {` The `, 10` is just the [radix (base)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), specifying that the major version will be parsed in the decimal system.

Comment: ahhh :) clear as water. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite simple with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "/video/videoK.mp4",
            ogv: "/video/videoK.ogg"
        }).jPlayer("play");

        $('article.about-k').hide();
        olark('api.box.hide');
    },
    swfPath: "/scripts/",
    supplied: "m4v, ogv",
    size: {
        width: "100%",
        height: ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) < 9)
          ? "400px"
          : "auto"
    },
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    click: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("play");
    },
    ended: function () {
        $('.jplayer-k').hide();
        $('article.about-k').show();
    }
})
```

If you don't like that (e.g. because of a more complex condition), you still can use a simple variable:

```
var height = "auto";
if (/* IE too old */)
    height = "400px";
$…({
      … // huge config object
      height: height,
      …
});
```

Comment: I'm aware of ternary operators on php. No issue there. Seems quite a nice solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if('<?= $cookie; ?>' > '1' || $(window).width() <= 768) {
          $('.jplayer-k').remove();
          $('article.about-k').show();
       }
       height = $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9 ? '400px' : 'auto';
         $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () 
            {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", 
                {
                    m4v: "/video/videoK.mp4",
                    ogv: "/video/videoK.ogg"
                }).jPlayer("play");

                $('article.about-k').hide();
                olark('api.box.hide');
            },
            swfPath: "/scripts/",
            supplied: "m4v, ogv",
            size: {
                width: "100%",
                height: height
            },
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            click: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("play");
            },
            ended: function() {
                $('.jplayer-k').hide();
                $('article.about-k').show();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
I added to code above the Fabriccio Matte suggestion so your code dont fail with IE10

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var playerObj = { ready : function () { /* ... */ }, size : /* AUTO */ };
if (/*stupid IE TEST*/) {
    playerObj.size.height = "...";
}

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer(playerObj);
```

Separate your configuration from your processes, and it becomes much less of a hassle.

Also, like @Bergi said, a ternary-operation:

```
value = (test_with_optional_parentheses) ? passed_value : failed_value;
```

...or in this case, as an object parameter:

```
{ value : (test_with_optional_parentheses) ? passed_value : failed_value };
```

Works perfectly well for changing one thing, inline, in the middle of a configuration object.

Keep my advice in mind for organizing large blocks of code, when you start confusing what you need to do with what you're currently doing.
Keep Bergi's advice in mind for when you need to set one single value (at a time), based on a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {

            if('<?= $cookie; ?>' > '1' || $(window).width() <= 768) {
              $('.jplayer-k').remove();
              $('article.about-k').show();
           }

            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () 
            {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", 
                {
                    m4v: "/video/videoK.mp4",
                    ogv: "/video/videoK.ogg"
                }).jPlayer("play");

                $('article.about-k').hide();
                olark('api.box.hide');
            },
            swfPath: "/scripts/",
            supplied: "m4v, ogv",
            size: {
                width: "100%",
                height: ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<9) ? "400px" : "auto"
            },
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            click: function() {
                $(this).jPlayer("play");
            },
            ended: function() {
                $('.jplayer-k').hide();
                $('article.about-k').show();
            }
        })
```